# Samba4/LDAP authentication and nginx

Tags: authentication, nginx, active-directory, ldap, samba

Before i start with my problem:
I've got a website which is protected by a reverse proxy (nginx). So the client is not allowed to connect directly to the website. It must connect to nginx and nginx shows then the content of the website.

Now i wanted to add more "security" features. I installed samba4 as it is usable as a AD DC and wanted to use LDAP (which is included in samba4?) to authenticate the clients which are trying to reach the website.
So before a client can actually see the website it must connect to nginx and then authenticate itself (with LDAP credentials) and then it can view the websites content.

I configured nginx with the module ldap_http_authentication (see configuration below) and it is working. When the client tries to view the website i need to login with some LDAP Credentials, but when i try to authenticate the client it just doesn't work. it says that the LDAP credentials are wrong. 
How can i add LDAP users when LDAP comes with samba? I just don't know which credentials to use. I added some users to samba like "test" and tried to use their credentials to authenticate, but they don't work as well.
So which credentials do i have to use for "binddn" and "binddn_passwd"? Where do I have to create them or get them?

My nginx ldap configuration:

```
ldap_server adds {
    url "ldap://192.168.50.131/dc=test,dc=dom?sAMAccountName?sub?";
    binddn "TEST\\USERNAME";
    binddn_passwd "password";
    connect_timeout 5s;
    bind_timeout 5s;
    request_timeout 5s;
    require valid_user;
    satisfy any;
     }
```

Thanks!

edit:
i tried to add some users with the command:

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=test,dc=dom -W -f add_user.ldif
```

but it just returns:
"Enter LDAP Password: ldap_bind: Strong(er) authentication required (8) additional info: BindSimple: Transport encryption required."

Btw: I've never set an LDAP Password, i just installed samba4. That's all!

Answer (score 1):

By default samba4 require start_tls.

For a start you should try to switch the url to ldaps://

Then you need:

- if you don't have a certified certificate

`ssl_check_cert off`

- a certificate for the tls transaction

`ssl_ca_file /etc/pki/tls/certs/whatever.crt`

For ldapXXXXX commands you need the -Z switch

You also need to check that you ldap.conf file contains the URI and BASE:

```
URI ldaps://ldap.server.com
BASE "dc=domain,dc=example,dc=com"
```

You also need the 2 following:

- a client certificate for the tls transaction

`TLS_CACERT=/etc/pki/tls/certs/whatever.crt`

- What to do if certificate is not valid

`TLS_REQCERT allow`